# Specify unique DHCP hostnames for multiple network interfaces

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp

I am running Ubuntu Server 20.04 in a VM under ESXi on my home server. I would like the VM to have two unique IP addresses, with the goal of being able to run two separate instances of PiHole in docker containers.

I have configured two network adapters on the VM, and then configured /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml as:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: true
    ens192:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

After running `netplan apply`, I have two interfaces, each with their own IP via DHCP.

```
# ifconfig
ens160: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.212  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
...
ens192: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.213  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
...
```

I have then edited `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` by commenting out the default 'send host-name' option and replacing it with two interface-specific options:

```
#send host-name = gethostname();
interface "ens160" {
    send host-name = "something-else-1";
}

interface "ens192" {
    send host-name = "something-else-2";
}
```

It's this step that does not seem to work. The DHCP server (Unifi) still reports the hostname as 'experimental'. In fact, I tried just changing the existing `gethostname()` line to just have some other hostname, and even that does not seem to work.

I tried changing `/etc/hostname` to use something different, and that did work. So it seems like the options in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` are just being ignored for some reason.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is that each interface needs a different DHCP "state machine." To do that you assign each one a different client id like this.

```
# send host-name = gethostname();
interface "enp2s0" {
    send dhcp-client-identifier "officemac";
    send host-name "officemac";
}
interface "enp2s0:0" {
    send dhcp-client-identifier "media";
    send host-name "media";
}
```